# Adding and removing codes in every line in windows

Tags: windows

I have lines like the ones shown below.

```
abcbasndo
bacmaisca
ascmasoc
```

Now, I need to take out the first three characters of every line and add **AAA** at the start and end of each line, so that it looks like the one shown below.

```
AAAabcAAA
AAAbacAAA
AAAascAAA
```

I am using **windows**.

Please help.

Comment: Where do you have these lines? In a file? Or are these filenames?

Comment: You mean first & last three characters should be replaced with **AAA**. Am I Right?

Comment: Specify programming language, data types etc. Question is unanswerable at the moment.

Comment: The specs say "windows". Given that limitation, you're free to offer up any solution that will run on Windows: cmd, powershell, cygwin, gnuwin32, gcc, msvc, and a plethora of other possibilities :-) I'm not sure _what_ you meant by "data types, etc" since it seems a simple string morphing exercise but I have to disagree on the answerability front.

Comment: @paxdiablo Perhaps the strings live in multi-line edit controls. Sure you can answer but you'd need to be very lucky to hit upon the answer that the asker is hoping for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This little `cmd` script will do the job for you:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (qq.txt) do (
    set var=%%a
    echo AAA!var:~0,3!AAA
)
endlocal
```

See the following transcript:

```
C:\Pax> type qq.txt
abcbasndo
bacmaisca
ascmasoc

C:\Pax> qq
AAAabcAAA
AAAbacAAA
AAAascAAA
```

The `for` loop grabs each line in the `qq.txt` file (without `delims=`, it would use spaces within the line as delimiters) and puts it in `%%a`.

The body of the `for` loop puts that value into `var` and then uses the substring operator to get the first three characters.

I haven't tested what will happen if the line has less than three characters since (1) you didn't specify what you expected; and (2) it should be fairly easy to expand this script to handle it.